# From where this Laplace transform for tracking error came?

Tags: sampling

> System for estimating the tracking error in an A-D converter.
>   [image]
>
> Let $e_i(t)$ be ramp function with slope $e_i'$ and assume that the sampling switch is closed at $t = 0$, at which time $e_i = e_0$. Then
>
> $$E_i(s) - E_0(s) = \frac{e_i^2}{s^2}-\frac{(e_i'/s^2)(1/(sC))}{R + 1/(sC)} \tag{1}\label{A}.$$

I understand that transfer function of this system is $\frac{(1/(sC))}{R + 1/(sC)},$ and it is equal to $\frac{E_0(s)}{E_i(s)},$ but from where $(\ref{A})$  came?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly noted
$$
\frac{E_o(s)}{E_i(s)} = \frac{1/sC}{R+1/sC}.
$$

But it also says $e_i(t)$ is a ramp with slope $e_i'$, so its Laplace transform is given by $E_i(s) = \frac{e_i'}{s^2}$.

Now just do some algebra:

$$
\frac{E_i(s)-E_o(s)}{E_i(s)} = 1-\frac{E_o(s)}{E_i(s)} = 1-\frac{1/sC}{R+1/sC}
$$
which gives
\begin{eqnarray}
E_i(s)-E_o(s) &=& \left( 1-\frac{1/sC}{R+1/sC} \right) E_i(s)\\
& =& \left(1-\frac{1/sC}{R+1/sC}\right)\frac{e_i'}{s^2}\\
&=& \frac{e_i'}{s^2}-\frac{(e_i'/s^2)(1/sC)}{R+1/sC}.
\end{eqnarray}